# Fetch multiple rows of a single column and assign them to different variables in an array in php

Tags: php, sql

i want to take value of all the subjects on year 2019 one by one and assign them in a variable like $sub1, $sub2 from the following table. how can i do so?
[image: database]

the query i am using is as follows

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `Regular Subjects` where Year='$year'";
 $r=$con->query($sql);

if($r->num_rows>0){
 while($subjects=$r->fetch_assoc(){

 $sub=$subjects["Subject"];
 echo $sub;

};
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself numbering variables like $sub1 and $sub2, you should probably think about using an array instead.

Comment: can you tell me how can i imlement array for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array say known as `$data` to store the data so that you can retrieve it later

Assuming that your code is correct so that it can retrieve the data as $subjects["Subject"] in the loop

Then change the block:

```
while($subjects=$r->fetch_assoc(){
 $sub=$subjects["Subject"];
 echo $sub;
};
```

to

```
$data = array();
$index=1;

while($subjects=$r->fetch_assoc(){
 $subx=$subjects["Subject"];
// echo $sub;
 $data["sub".$index]=$subx;
 $index++;
};
```

Then you will have the data stored in `$data["sub1"]`, `$data["sub2"]`... and so on